# add package to project programmatically using gradle in android studio

Tags: android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I have a package which I want to add it to my project as a new package, not a new module is it possible?
 thanks for any hint or clue.
**Update**
my package is on a repo and I want to add them as a new package, not a new lib module

Answer (score 0):

New package i am assuming you have a package with classes not any full deploy-able  module in case of package just copy and past your package in the src directory change package name in classes as required some time. import R.java for claases remove all error import 3rd party libs if require boom its done

Comment: thanks for your attention i update my question please look again

Comment: just copy-paste source and tends to remove error nothing else